# HttpWebRequest is getting stream even without internet connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I am using below code to send a byte array to a site. Why this code is not throwing an exception even when there is no internet connection?.Even when no connection is there I am able to get stream and able to write to it.I expect it to throw an exception at `Stream postStream = request1.EndGetRequestStream(result)`.Anyone got any idea why its behaving like this.

```
     private void UploadHttpFile()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(myUrl));
        request.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);


        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows Vista;)";

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        request.BeginGetRequestStream(GetStream, request);


    }

    private void GetStream(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            using (Stream postStream = request1.EndGetRequestStream(result))
            {
                int len = postBody.Length;
                len += mainBody.Length;
                len += endBody.Length;
                byte[] postArray = new byte[len + 1];
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody.ToString()).CopyTo(postArray, 0);
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mainBody).CopyTo(postArray, postBody.Length);
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(endBody).CopyTo(postArray, postBody.Length + mainBody.Length);
                postStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect it's buffering everything until you're done writing, at which point it will be able to use the content length immediately. If you set:

```
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
```

then I suspect it will fail at least when you write to the stream.

Btw, your calculation of the required length for `postArray` appears to be assuming one byte per character, which won't always be the case... and you're calling `ToString` on `postBody` which *looks* like it's redundant. I'm not sure why you're trying to write in a single call anyway... *either* you could call Write three times:

```
byte[] postBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);
postStream.Write(postBodyBytes, 0, postBodyBytes.Length);
// etc
```

*or* (preferrably) just use a `StreamWriter`:

```
using (Stream postStream = request1.EndGetRequestStream(result))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(postStream)
    {
        writer.Write(postBody);
        writer.Write(mainBody);
        writer.Write(endBody);
    }
}
```

It's *also* unclear why you've added 1 to the required length when initializing `postArray`. Are you *trying* to send an extra "0" byte at the end of the data?

Comment: `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` is not available in WP7.I can see only `AllowReadStreamBuffering`.

Comment: @Vaysage: Ah... in that case you may well not be able to find out until you try to get the response. Given that you're not really doing *much* work in the writing code, is that a particular hardship?

Comment: yes i need to send a zero at the end .The methods you posted are best way to do this ,I will use this method only

Comment: @Vaysage: Including the extra 0 at the end is *slightly* tricky - you'd need to flush the writer within the using statement and write the extra byte directly to the stream *still within the inner using statement* as otherwise the StreamWriter will close the stream.